# How to filter a data when it's null?

Tags: php, yii2

I try to make a new query search in **PlanificacionSearch** but I don't know how to filters results where the value *'asistencia'* is only null. In the code below whit this condition, it returns all the elements, ignoring the null condition on that value.

In SQL, this is the desired query:

```
SELECT asistencia FROM gestion_talleres.planificacion
WHERE rutProfesor = <session_id> AND asistencia IS NULL
```

And this is the query I wrote in Yii 2:

```
$query
            ->andFilterWhere(['asistencia' => null])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'rutProfesor', Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor]);
```

The condition for *'rutProfesor'* is already working, but not the *'asistencia'* one. I need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When building WHERE conditions based on input from end users, you usually want to ignore those input values, that are empty. For example, in a search form that allows you to search by username and email, you would like to ignore the username/email condition if the user does not enter anything in the username/email input field. You can achieve this goal by using the filterWhere() method:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#filter-conditions

`andFilterWhere(['asistencia' => null])` work only if the value is not null

if you need  check for null condition  you shoud use andWhere

```
andWhere(['asistencia' => null])
```

that is always executed or where with multiple value eg:

```
 // ...WHERE (`status` = 10) AND (`type` IS NULL) AND (`id` IN (4, 8, 15))
 $query->where([
   'status' => 10,
   'type' => null,
   'id' => [4, 8, 15],
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$query
    ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'asistencia', null])
    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'rutProfesor', Yii::$app->user->identity->rutProfesor]);
```